# Let  be number of sixes and  be number of fours one gets when rolling six dice. Find the expected value and variance of  + .

Tags: probability-theory

If we introduce an indicator variable $B_i$ for getting 6 on the roll $i$ (rolls are independent) and define $Y$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{6} B_i$, then $EY = \sum_{i=1}^{6} E{B_i} = 6 * \frac{1}{6} = 1$. Same for $Z$, so the $E[Y+Z] = 2$. But I'm not sure how to compute the variance:
$$Var[Y+Z] = E[(Y+Z)^2] - (E[Y+Z])^2$$
Expanding the first term gives us:
$$E[(Y+Z)^2] = E[Y^2] + E[Z^2] + 2E[YZ]$$
I have no idea how to find the last term, as it seems like $Y$ and $Z$ are dependent. I can, perhaps, try finding all possible combinations of $Y$ and $Z$ and computing the probability for each one, but it seems like a lot of tedious work (even considering some clever shortcuts).
$$$$
Is there an easier way to solve this task?

Comment: An easier approach... rather than thinking about a die with six sides... how about a die with three sides (*or if that bothers you... a six-sided die but sides 1,1,2,2,3,3*) and asking the question about the expected value and variance of the number of $3$'s rolled.  Can you see why that's the same problem, just worded differently?

Comment: Yes, it is probably easier to work with $Y+Z$ as counting the number of rolls that are either $4$ or $6$, since these are mutually exclusive outcomes.

Comment: Oh, this is a really clever idea! So events of rolling either $4$ or $6$ on the dice $i$ are independent and their probability is $\frac{1}{3}$. And the variance of their sum (which is $Y+Z$) is the sum of variances, so the answer should be $6 * (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}^2) = \frac{4}{3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z=Y+Z$ is the number of 6's or 4's that is a binomial random variable

$$Z\sim\text{Bin}\left[6;\frac{2}{6}\right]$$

thus

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=6\cdot\frac{2}{6}=2$$

$$\mathbb{V}[Z]=6\cdot\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{6}=\frac{4}{3}$$

---

this is the probability mass function of $Z$

[image]